# Why can't I run the TortoiseSVN 64 MSI as Administrator, under Windows 7?

Tags: tortoisesvn

When right clicking on the TortiseSVN MSI, why can't I see the option to "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: Can you explain what is not working?

Comment: I installed Subversion 64 bits no right menu appeared I thought it was because I didn't run it with admin right. Seems like it was due to 32 bit previous installation. It's now solved.

Comment: That's totally different from the description in your question. If you only said that from the beginning...

Comment: This is not programming-related. Belongs to SuperUser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to right-click and "Run As Administrator" on MSI files. MSI files already declare internally whether they need admin rights or not, and windows installer will prompt for elevation as appropriate.